# How to sort and enter data using CSV writer or DictWriter

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, export-to-csv

My CSV header looks like this

```
ID | First Name | Last Name | Email
```

And I have many dictionary to add as rows in a loop which looks like this.

```
{'ID':1, 'First Name':'John', 'Last Name':'Doe','Email':'test@example.com'}
{'Email':'another@example.com', 'First Name':'Jane', 'Last Name':'Doe', 'ID':3}
```

The csv header columns and the keys in dictionary are exactly similar, but as you can see the dictionary is jumbled in order. How do I add each row to the csv file in a way which the correct item in dictionary is added under its column in csv?

Using Python 3.5.2

Comment: The `fieldnames` argument to a [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) determines the order of the columns/fields of the csv file that is written. This argument is a sequence and its order determine the the order of the fields in the rows of the file when they're written. See the example code in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CSV `DictWriter()` could be used as follows:

```
import csv

data = [{'ID':1, 'First Name':'John', 'Last Name':'Doe','Email':'test@example.com'}, 
        {'Email':'another@example.com', 'First Name':'Jane', 'Last Name':'Doe', 'ID':3}]

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=['ID', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email'])
    csv_output.writeheader()
    csv_output.writerows(data)
```

Giving you `output.csv` containing:

```
ID,First Name,Last Name,Email
1,John,Doe,test@example.com
3,Jane,Doe,another@example.com
```